# Visual Studio 2015 missing core assemblies/namespaces?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

Can someone explain to me how to use/accuire access to vs built-in classes like MusicProperties or ImageProperties listed here? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.aspx

My visual studio doesnt recognize it`s namespace even though I have installed latest windows 10 sdk, as listed in the requirements table:
"Universal, introduced version 10.0.10240.0".

Do I have to use explicitly winForms or WPF etc to have access to specific libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an [Universal app or Windows Runtime app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) to be able to access that namespace.

Pick any of these (note that some project types can have another subset of features enabled):

> [image: new project dialog]

Comment: Cant I use it in widnows forms by any way?